# Cannot convert char to char*[] and illegal sizeof operand

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I am trying to read from a file and put each new line/entry in to an array. However, I am more primarily familiar with C# and C++ isn't my thing. The reason I need to do this is for a project and I am the only one that is willing to do this part.

I do not know how to properly convert character types or if it is possible. I have tried searching around the internet but have not found any answers regarding something like my issue here. Also, because I do not know what causes an illegal sizeof operand I do not know what is wrong here.

```
#include "..\STDInclude.h"
// TODO: Fill that list with names
char* Bots::NameList[] = {};

void Bots::GetNames()
{
    using namespace std;

    ifstream file("bot_names.txt");
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
        {
            file >> Bots::NameList[i];
        }
    }
}

void Bots::Initialize()
{
    // Replace staff array with custom one
    *(char***)Addresses::BotArray1 = Bots::NameList;
    *(char***)Addresses::BotArray2 = Bots::NameList;
    *(char***)Addresses::BotArray3 = Bots::NameList;

    // Apply new array size
    int size = (sizeof(Bots::NameList) / sizeof(Bots::NameList[0]));
    *(BYTE*)Addresses::BotArraySize1 = size;
    *(BYTE*)Addresses::BotArraySize2 = size;
    *(BYTE*)Addresses::BotArraySize3 = size;
    *(BYTE*)Addresses::BotArraySize4 = size;
}
```

Comment: this question is incomplete, there is not enough information to form an answer, `Addresses` is undefined, `Bots` is undefined.

Comment: line 1:  `\S` means same as `S` I think you mean `/S`

Comment: Bots is the current class I am working in and Addresses is another class that replaces addresses memory addresses in a game.

Comment: @Jasen it worked fine when the array was hardcoded manually.

Comment: Please include the (copy-and-pasted) error messages in the question.

Comment: There are still not enough stars. If being a three-star-programmer is not positive, what does it mean for a C++ programmer?

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in C++ are of fixed size.  So when you write  `char* Bots::NameList[] = {}` , you have an empty array of c-strings (aka `char*`).

Worse,  when you later write `file >> Bots::NameList[i];` you are writing null terminated c-strings to uninitialized pointers, which will cause memory corruption.

Unless fundamental rewrite, this code is doomed to fail.   I strongly suggest that you replace use of `char*` with `std::string` and that you switch from fixed size arrays to vectors.

```
std::vector<std::string> Bots::NameList;

void Bots::GetNames()
{
    ...
        for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
        {
            string s;   // space separated strings ? sure ? 
            file >> s;  //     or getline(file, s) if you want lines
            NameList.push_back(s); 
        }
    }
}
```

**Aditional remark:**

I can't tell for sure, as I don't know the definition of `Addresses` members, but statements like the following are relatively suspicious:

```
*(char***)Addresses::BotArray1 = Bots::NameList;
```

It suggests that `Addresses::BotArray1` is an array or a pointer.  But the fact that you are casting with `(char***)` suggest that you tried to fix a type mismatch. And dereferencing the casted pointer will make sense only if `BotArray` points already to a valid `char**` pointer in which the address of `NameList` should be stored.

Comment: Geeze. We even used almost the same wording.

Comment: ;-) and replied in the same minute (at less than 20 seconds interval)

Comment: @Critophe and other user; thank you for explaining what was wrong here and helping me fix it.

Comment: `char* Bots::NameList[] = {}` causes undefined behaviour. See [dcl.init.aggr]/4: "An array of unknown size initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer-list containing n initializer-clauses,
*where n shall be greater than zero*, [...]"

Comment: @MattMcNabb I supposed it was the definition of a static array which size is defined in the Bots class, such as [here](http://ideone.com/GNxnZC).

Comment: @Christophe You're right. However then it would not be an empty array (unless you meant something other than "zero-sized").

Answer (score 2):

In C++ an array must be sized when created and then it is fixed, so `char* Bots::NameList[] = {};` is a zero element array and is stuck that way. Worse, in `file >> Bots::NameList[i]` nothing ever allocated storage for Bots::NameList[i], so your program is writing into uninitialized memory. Probably a BOOM waiting to happen. I'm going to suggest something completely different.

in the Bots class definition:

```
std::vector<std::string> NameList;
```

Then later...

```
void Bots::GetNames()
{
    std::ifstream file("bot_names.txt");
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
        {
            std::string temp;
            file >> temp;
            NameList.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

`Addresses::BotArray1..N` must also become `std::vector`s and `Addresses::BotArraySize1..N` are made redundant because vectors know their size.

Comment: There are no zero-sized C-style arrays in Standard C++ ; OP's code causes UB .

Comment: @MattMcNabb Good to know. All I had to test it against was a pretty old GCC

Comment: You can use gcc.godbolt.org to test modern compilers' error messages